# ngx smart modal with angular lazy loading not working

Tags: angular, lazy-loading

Hi im using ngx smart modal for pop up in angular. Its working fine for me. But when i am doing it inside of a lazy loading componenent its showing me error Cannot find modal with identifier signDocument.

I have imported the said component and used in declaration as well as entry components too.

```
 import { SignDocumentComponent } from './sign-document/sign-document.component';
 @NgModule({
  declarations: [
  SignDocumentComponent
  ],
  imports: [
   NgxSmartModalModule.forRoot()
   ],
   providers: [
   NgxSmartModalService
    ],
   entryComponents: [
    SignDocumentComponent
    ]
    })
   export class AgreementsModule { }
```

This is my lazy loading module. Can anyone help pls

Answer (score 1):

If you are using smart modal inside lazy loading component, in your lazy loading module import smartmodalmodule

```
import { NgxSmartModalModule } from "ngx-smart-modal";
```

And add it in your imports as below

```
  imports: [
  NgxSmartModalModule.forChild()
   ]
```